# Is there a Datetime format which not change the output date value?

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a string in an XML which is a datetime with a timezone and I would like to change it to a DateTime format in C#.

The problem is that it go from the string format to datetime format, the value change due to the timezone.

So I would like to know how to change the xml string to c# datetime without the modification of the value.

The string xml value is :

> 2014-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+02:00

and when I apply the datetime format it goes to :

> 12/31/2013 10:00:00 PM

Here is my c# code to convert string to datetime :

```c
Convert.ToDateTime(datestringXml);
```

I need to sort the date with the Max() and Min() function

I expect the output to be 01/01/2014... (I don't care about the hours, minutes and seconds)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8#formatting-03)

Comment: You could split the xml on the `+` and take the [0] element and pass that to your `Convert.ToDateTime` from there it's just formatting the string to show `"MM/dd/yyyy"` `(Convert.ToDateTime(yourXMLString.Split('+')[0])).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Comment: Thank you so much @CharlesMay!! Your code solved my problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a DateTime object instead of a DateTimeOffset object. The offset part +02:00 doesn't fit in a DateTime object so it calculates the DateTime for you. You wouldn't have this issue if you'd just parse the value into a DateTimeOffset object.

Answer (score 1):

You see a different converted date because there is a +02:00 in your starting date. The conversion is right.
If you need only the day, month and year you could do a parse of the original string and create the new date with the read values.

Comment: Thank you for this information! Now I understand why the date value changed.